# Github Pages NPM run deploy fails with error code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages

Whenever I run npm run deploy I get an error and it fails to upload. I am trying to update my gh-pages sight.

This is the entire error code.

I also have a glitch where whenever I get it to successfully update something goes wrong with my react-scripts and I have to re-install them to get npm to start to work again. Unsure if they are related.

```html
$ npm run deploy

> visualizer@0.1.0 predeploy E:\CS Projects\visualizer
> npm run build


> visualizer@0.1.0 build E:\CS Projects\visualizer
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

src\Algorithms\Prims Algorithm.js
  Line 2:20:   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 25:19:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 25:33:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 63:30:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 71:23:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 80:47:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq

src\Components\pathfind.js
  Line 24:6:    React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initializeGrid'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 103:31:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                                                                                eqeqeq
  Line 104:31:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                                                                                eqeqeq
  Line 150:44:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                                                                                eqeqeq
  Line 295:20:  Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'visualizing'                                no-loop-func

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  41.79 KB         build\static\js\2.b9ab6867.chunk.js
  2.52 KB (+58 B)  build\static\js\main.b353fac3.chunk.js
  785 B            build\static\js\runtime-main.2607e426.js
  611 B (+45 B)    build\static\css\main.578142da.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /Pathfinding-Maze/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment


> visualizer@0.1.0 deploy E:\CS Projects\visualizer
> gh-pages -d build

error: unable to create file node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/content-v2/sha512/78/ac/b49db122e8e72e696370d9fc2742bbf9ae084cf44a147fe437884effcd329d671056ff9504190f0a0ce09e52dad244776aedcf305f95d9f3f90293f9f9c6: Filename too long
error: unable to create file node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/content-v2/sha512/d2/cb/724f99d1995df1b17a7e65705e6c783e73d44f178b4bb352fc5b1588418ee5595063c9a46236db95f86f6b46f9e8fee0a534182759c55feb47f195464889: Filename too long
error: unable to create file node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/content-v2/sha512/e4/c3/82f9364e965d57a5328c7dd4166f52a573f96425bc1cb7c898b2998ae7e8c7b51f60ef6e74ccdf2886b77be998148373abb259f93a8cd4170ffc684cf7ff: Filename too long
error: unable to create file node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/content-v2/sha512/ea/1a/8b9daf49a0111aad5fa6c17a4de12c7722a09da42a80c0adf1ad21c72b041c4640010d7a441065940e6f0f28f66d61ebaece46df20b0a39f4b7776ac5534: Filename too long
Updating files: 100% (35889/35889), done.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/gh-pages'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! visualizer@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the visualizer@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex Bianchi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-25T01_52_02_193Z-debug.log
```

Comment: useEffect will re-run the effect callback whenever any of the items in dependency array changes (e.g. loading goes from false to true).

Comment: The warning you are receiving is because you have used buttonValue in your effect callback but not included in the dependency array. So when you call the setButton() in click handler of the button, nothing happens because the useEffect won't detect any change to re-run the effect callback.

Comment: However, I suggest that you change the implementation, useEffect should be used for Side Effects (e.g. triggering a list update when the user selects a dropdown), not the effect themselves (Clicking on a submit buttons).

Comment: @akhilchoudhary I use useEffect to initialize my grid on startup with         
  useEffect(() => {initializeGrid()}, []);  I have a version of this code deployed right now and its working fine so I wonder if something else is the problem.